# Google BigQuery - Can I authenticate the user who can play with bigquery data by using "OAuth2.0 Client ID" or "API Keys" credentials?

Tags: google-bigquery

In my application, we are using Python SDK (google-cloud-bigquery) to perform below operations with the BigQuery.

- Authentication
- Running query for Read/Write operations

As of now I am able to use "Service Accounts" credentials for above opertions. But now I want to know whether we can use "OAuth2.0 Client ID" or "API Keys" credentials for above operations? If we can use, Could you please suggest me how to achieve these?

I am using below code snippet for "Service Accounts" credentials.

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import os

    def getClient(credentialsFilePath):
        response = None
        try:
            os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = credentialsFilePath
            response = bigquery.Client()
    
        except Exception as e:
            response = "{error}".format(error=e.args[0])
        finally:
            os.environ.pop("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
    
        return response
```

Thanks in Advance,
Srinivas Bommaraboina

I want to add all possible authentication mechanisms in my App by using Python client libraries.